# How to dynamic change the type of QWidget shown to the user

Tags: c++, qt

I am having a problem to make the QWidget change dynamic as the user change the index in combobox. I have a slot connected to the currentIndexChanged(int) from the combobox. This slot should change the widget shown to the user according to the index of combobox.
I tried the following code, but didn’t work:

```
void Form::setMetodoWidget(int index)
{
    Form2* form2;// a different widget to show
    if(index == 0 ){
        ui->widget = new QWidget;

    }
    if(index == 1){
        form2 = new Form2;
        ui->widget = form2;
    }
}
```

I tried to add form2 in a vertical layout and then add to the widget, but then he gives this error message:
Attempting to set QLayout “” on QWidget “widget”, which already has a layout

I would like to know how to do the “Promote to” function of QtDesigner,but in code.
Thanks.

Comment: The type o' QWidget? That's what I think of when I see this title. :)

Comment: Solved:http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/45364/